# Multi Site Install Problem

Tags: 8, files, multi-sites

I downloaded drupal 8 and performed an install without any noticable incident, after completing the install I attempted to use drush to install 4 additional sites, I added the sites to the sites .php file.

However I am having various problems with the sites. Two of the sites load ok, another one loads with this screen `“The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.”` and a plain white screen. Another of them loads with what is mostly just text and plain text links, but no theme/colors etc.

The only thing that I have noticed that is abnormal is that in my `sites/default/files` dir I have 3 config_*** dirs. I am not adverse to beginning the entire process over gain, I simply would like to know the exact steps I must take to get all of the sites installed and working correctly.

I really don't understand d8 all that well but I feel like there is some config issues) going on. Any and all help would be very welcomed. I would really like to get these sites up and runing. Also can anyone please advise the correct owner and permissions for the `sites/files` dir?

I did notice that there is a default.services.yml only in the default dir not the other sub sites.

Comment: Can you provide the full drush command you used to initialize the additional sites, and the resulting output?  Also, [enabling debugging options](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374) will provide more information on the cause of the unexpected error.